# Postfix user not found in virtual alias table

Tags: postfix

Does anyone know why I get this error:

```
postfix/error[4711]: 707A9189C6B0: to=<person.example.com@example.com>, orig_to=<person@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
```

I am unable to get any mails from any address, Running Debian Lenny with Virtualmin.

Thanks
RayQuang

Comment: That to address looks wrong, instead of `person.example.com@example.com` it should be `person@example.com`. Is that a typing error in your question?

Comment: It has always been like this, my mail address is person@example.com and it gets converted to the user person.example.com (which is my actual username). I copied this from mail.log.

Comment: The output of 'postconf -n' would be a good start.

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix it, turns out I changed the hostname because I accidentally set it wrongly in the install. However after i changed the hostname but I forgot to change the allowed domains list. works now :)  Thanks for your help, RayQuang

Comment: can you make that the answer to your question, rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, turns out I changed the hostname because I accidentally set it wrongly in the install. However after i changed the hostname but I forgot to change the allowed domains list. works now :) Thanks for your help, RayQuang